# How do I calculate this checksum?

Tags: checksum, crc

I have an alarm system that I have configured to send SMS messages to my phone as well as over Ethernet.

Here a few of the SMSes I receive:

```
5522 18 1137 00 003 1C76
5522 18 3137 00 003 3278
5522 18 1130 00 002 E36E
5522 18 1401 00 001 ED6E
5522 18 1302 00 003 ED70
5522 18 1302 00 004 EE71
5522 18 1302 00 009 F376
5522 18 3147 00 009 417F
5522 18 1137 00 004 1D77
5522 18 3137 00 009 3379
5522 18 1602 00 000 0870
```

The first 4 bytes are the account number, the next 2 are always 18, the next 4 are event codes, 2 group bytes and 3 zone numbers. At the end there are 4 bytes which I suspect is some kind of checksum.

This is some kind of Ademco Contact ID format. However, I do not recognize the checksum.
It's not a time stamp as the last message (0870) is sent periodically and is always the same.

When sending via DTMF 0 should have value 10, but I do not know if that is the case with SMSes. Most likely not.

Comment: Why not ask Ademco for precision ?

Comment: It's actually described in a document: DC-07-2001.04 but that costs money and isn't really worth it for me on this hobby project. It's referred to as a CRC checksum.

Comment: I am afraid that reversing it is the way to go.

Comment: How about a large sample of received SMSes as an attached file ?

Comment: Actually, the listed SMSer are all that I have.

Comment: According to a spec, DC-01, which deals with similar matters this could be a CRC-16 with a 0xA001 poly, but I still can't get that to match properly.

Answer (score 1):

The checksum formula in Ademco's Contact ID is calculated using the formula:

S= HEX Checksum which is one digit.

(Sum of all message digits + S) MOD 15 = 0

and if the value is equal to 10 the checksum digit is 0.
The official Contact ID specification is here:http://li0r.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/sia-dc-05-1999-09_contact_id.pdf

So, using `5522 18 1602 00 000 0870` as an example:

```
LET C = checksum

5+5+2+2+1+8+1+6+2=32

(32+S) modulo 15 is congruent to 0
```

We then need the closest multiple of 15 going higher than 32 which would be 45.

```
45-32=13
```

Lets test that.

```
45 modulo 15 is congruent to 0
```

It is correct however, as Contact ID is 16 digits and you have 19 I would suspect that your panel is using a different proprietary implementation of Contact ID. If you post the make/model of the panel that this came from I may be able to explain things further.

I hope this answers your question!

-Alex

P.S.: To calculate mod use a percent sign in Google
P.P.S: The document that describes Contact ID is actually: DC-05-1999.09 the document you referenced is actually the computer interface communication protocol specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to correct AdemcoGuy's calculation as it seems to be incorrect:
So, the example was **5522 18 1602 00 000 0870**
We need to replace each 0 by 10.
So:
**5+5+2+2+1+8+1+6+10+2+10+10+10+10+10 = 92**

than 100-92 = 8

**So the cheksum is 8**

Anyway in the question the checksum seems missing and what is the last 4 digit only knows who manufactured the panel which has been send it :)

Answer (score 0):

`#ACCT MT QXYZ GG CCC` where:

- `ACCT`: 4 Digit Account number (0-9, B-F)
- `MT`: Message Type - Always 18
- `Q`: Event qualifier, which gives specific event information:

  - 1: New Event or Opening
  - 3: New Restore or Closing
  - 6: Previously reported condition still present (Status report)
- `XYZ`: Event code (3 Hex digits 0-9,B-F)
- `GG`: Group or Partition number (2 Hex digits 0-9, B-F). Use 00 to indicate that no specific group or partition information applies.
- `CCC`: Zone number (Event reports) or User (Open / Close reports) (3 Hexdigits 0-9,B-F ). Use 000 to indicate that no specific zone or user information applies.

To look up event codes see [this document](http://alarmsbc.com/tech/pdf/contactid.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: This is informative. But it doesn't answer the question, which was about the four digits which follow the `CCC`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while trying to figure out the checksums of my own alarm system (Woonveilig/Egardia) that seems to be using the same format. I found a [forum post on the german alarm forum](https://www.alarmforum.de/showthread.php?tid=12037&pid=75893) that contains a snippet of C code to calculate CRCs for the LUPUS alarm system. This CRC calculation method seems to match both my own and Lasse's SMS based system. Here's the C code converted to a simple calculation tool:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Code from: https://www.alarmforum.de/showthread.php?tid=12037&pid=75893

/**
* Fletcher Checksum.(LUPUS version, 16-bit)
*/
static unsigned int fletcher_sum(char* data, int len) {
    unsigned int sum1 = 0x0, sum2 = 0x0;
    while (len) {
        unsigned int tlen = (len > 256) ? 256 : len;
        len -= tlen;
        do {
            sum1 += *data++;
            sum1 = (sum1 & 0xff);
            sum2 += sum1;
            sum2 = (sum2 & 0xff);
        } while (--tlen);
    }
    return sum2 << 8 | sum1;
}

int main() {
    char input[50];
    int sum;
    printf("Enter input: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    sum = fletcher_sum(input, strlen(input)-1);
    printf("%x\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Example (first SMS from the question post):

```
# cc checksum.c
# ./a.out
Enter input: 5522 18 1137 00 003
1c76
```